# Speed up / reduce CPU load to draw bitmap in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, performance, bitmap

I have to draw a waterfall diagramm in Swift, and I am using a bitmap context, which is updated very fast, about 20 lines per seconds, at all I have about 400 lines to display - full width.

My CPU Load is about 100% at the moment, and I would like to know, if there is a better way, drawing this, to lower the CPU load.

```
func draw2(pixel:[rgba],width:Int,height:Int) -> UIImage
{   let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    var data = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: pixel)

    let bitmapContext = CGContext(data: data,
                                  width: width,
                                  height: height,
                                  bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                  bytesPerRow: 4*width,
                                  space: colorSpace,
                                  bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)


    let image = bitmapContext?.makeImage()

    return UIImage(cgImage: image!)

}
```

Thank you very much in common

Comment: Hi @Manuel- are you redrawing the entire image each time this is called? Assuming you are just adding new lines each time you could cache the existing image and just draw the new bits on top (much like you would cache drawn paths in a drawing app).

Comment: Hello Sparky, I change the pointer for data, so that it points to the new line. So I only add one line to the array, but yes I draw the entire image each time the function is called. Is it somehow possible to just draw one new line, and place the existing image one pixel lower ?

Answer (score 0):

From what you've told me you should be able to cache the image and only draw the incremental line each time. You need to keep a class parameter to store your image in:

```
var cachedImage : UIImage?
```

Each time you call your draw function do the following:

1. Draw the cached image (if it exists, on the first run it won't of course) using UIImage.draw(in:CGRect) (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624092-draw).
2. Draw your new paths.
3. Save the result back to cachedImage.

On each iteration of draw you obviously want to shift the rectangle by one pixel, and initialise your context to make room for the new line.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am not absolutely sure, if I understand it right.
Do I have to create a Context like this and place my cached Image inside?
`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(DrawImage.frame.size)
     var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
     cachedImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 1, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height - 1))`

Comment: Exactly. You can draw the cached image into the context and then  draw the new lines, then grab an image from the updated graphics context. I'm afraid I'm away from my desk right now so cannot test any code but that should work.

Comment: Thank you Sparky, I've tried this with just an example UIImage ( a jpg ) and I added a simple Line to the context. That works fine, and it looks exactly like what I need! But there is only one problem, how is it possible to add one line to my existing context, out of my pixel array? I am only able to create a whole context out of my pixel data, but I can't add this to an existing, or is there a trick for that? I googled around for that problem, but I can't find anything :/

Comment: Hi @Manuel, glad it's (sort of working). The only thing I can think of right now is to grab a UIImage from the newly drawn pixels and then draw that directly below the original image using UIImage.draw(at: CGPoint). The issue with that of course is that you need to ensure all your lines are complete lines and you have no partials, otherwise it's not going to work at all. I'm going to play around with this further as I'm finding it really instructive, I may put something together and add it to my GitHub in which case I'll send you a link.